# On Stripe's PaymentIntent, is it possible to use fetch request/ajax?

Tags: javascript, stripe-payment-intent

Hello stackoverflow gurus,

Newbie here, I am trying to use JavaScript's fetch request for Stripe's PaymentIntent.  It is currently working as a POST request to another page.  If I omit the redirection URL, it keeps spinning, and the payment never goes through.

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks!